# Checking for winner in TicTacToe?

Tags: c#, if-statement

What would be the best way to see (in a 2 player) game of Tic Tac Toe who won? Right now I'm using something similar to the following:

```
if (btnOne.Text == "X" && btnTwo.Text == "X" && btnThree.Text == "X")
{
    MessageBox.Show("X has won!", "X won!");
    return;
}
else
// I'm not going to write the rest but it's really just a bunch
// if statements.
```

So how do I get rid of the multiple if's?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something alongs:

```
rowSum == 3 || columnSum == 3 || diagnolSum == 3
```

.. ?

Comment: Nice update, I think I may go with this method but I'll leave the question unanswered to see if anyone else can come up with something better (we gotta let 'em have a chance, right?).

Comment: Extracted into another answer post.

Comment: This determines the game is finished but does not distinguish between teams.

Answer (score 3):

If you store your buttons in a multidimenstional array, you can write some extension methods to get the rows, columns and diagonals.

```
public static class MultiDimensionalArrayExtensions
{
  public static IEnumerable<T> Row<T>(this T[,] array, int row)
  {
    var columnLower = array.GetLowerBound(1);
    var columnUpper = array.GetUpperBound(1);

    for (int i = columnLower; i <= columnUpper; i++)
    {
      yield return array[row, i];
    }
  }

  public static IEnumerable<T> Column<T>(this T[,] array, int column)
  {
    var rowLower = array.GetLowerBound(0);
    var rowUpper = array.GetUpperBound(0);

    for (int i = rowLower; i <= rowUpper; i++)
    {
      yield return array[i, column];
    }
  }

  public static IEnumerable<T> Diagonal<T>(this T[,] array,
                                           DiagonalDirection direction)
  {
    var rowLower = array.GetLowerBound(0);
    var rowUpper = array.GetUpperBound(0);
    var columnLower = array.GetLowerBound(1);
    var columnUpper = array.GetUpperBound(1);

    for (int row = rowLower, column = columnLower;
         row <= rowUpper && column <= columnUpper;
         row++, column++)
   {
      int realColumn = column;
      if (direction == DiagonalDirection.DownLeft)
        realColumn = columnUpper - columnLower - column;

      yield return array[row, realColumn];
    }
  }

  public enum DiagonalDirection
  {
    DownRight,
    DownLeft
  }
}
```

And if you use a `TableLayoutPanel` with 3 rows and 3 columns, you can easily create your buttons programmably and store it into a `Button[3, 3]` array.

```
Button[,] gameButtons = new Button[3, 3];

for (int row = 0; column <= 3; row++)
  for (int column = 0; column <= 3; column++)
  {
    Button button = new Button();
    // button...
    gameLayoutPanel.Items.Add(button);
    gameButtons[row, column] = button;
  }
```

And to check for a winner:

```
string player = "X";
Func<Button, bool> playerWin = b => b.Value == player;
gameButtons.Row(0).All(playerWin) ||
// ...
gameButtons.Column(0).All(playerWin) ||
// ...
gameButtons.Diagonal(DiagonalDirection.DownRight).All(playerWin) ||
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way out would be to save the winnable positions as a data in an array and use a loop to check all possible winning conditions instead of multiple ifs statements

```
// winnable positions
var winnables = new[] {
    "012",
    "345",
    "678",
    "036",
    "147",
    "258",
    "048",
    "246"
};

// extracted from btnOne Two Three....
var gameState = new[] { "X", "O", "X", "whatever" };


string winner = null;

// check each winnable positions
foreach (var position in winnables) {

    var pos1 = int.Parse(position[0].ToString());
    var pos2 = int.Parse(position[1].ToString());
    var pos3 = int.Parse(position[2].ToString());

    if (gameState[pos1] == gameState[pos2] &&
        gameState[pos2] == gameState[pos3])
        winner = gameState[pos1];

}

// do we have a winner?
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(winner))
    /* we've got a winner */
```

Basically, don't use btnOne btnTwo btnThree, use a proper array of Buttons or an array that saves the game state in a more accessible format and it'll be easier to compute.

Comment: The int.Parse is a little ugly though... but it helps keeps the winnable position easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do things like this:

```
bool x_wins =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, 3)
        .SelectMany(i => new Func<int, string>[] { x => array[i, x], x => array[x, i] })
        .Concat(new Func<int, string>[] { x => array[x, x], x => array[2 - x, x], })
        .Where(f => String.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => f(x))) == "XXX")
        .Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you are no longer looking for an answer to this question. That said, someone might.

Using @fran-casadome's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15074857/265706) and @chakrit's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/740507/265706), I would do something like this. Hard-coded possibilities seem appropriate. Linq let's up wrap the logic in fluent steps. A nice use.

```cs
private bool IsWinner(char player) => new[]
{
  new[] { 0, 1, 2 },
  new[] { 3, 4, 5 },
  new[] { 6, 7, 8 },
  new[] { 0, 3, 6 },
  new[] { 1, 4, 7 },
  new[] { 2, 5, 8 },
  new[] { 0, 4, 8 },
  new[] { 2, 4, 6 }
}.Any(indexes => indexes.All(index => _data[index] == player));
```

Here's the rest, for context.

```cs
private readonly char[] _data =
  new[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

public bool GameOver { get; private set; } = false;

public char? WinningPlayer { get; private set; } = null;

public char CurrentPlayer { get; private set; } = 'x';

public void Play(int position)
{
  var index = Array.IndexOf(_data, position);

  if (GameOver || index == -1)
  {
    return;
  }

  if (GameOver = IsWinner(_data[index] = CurrentPlayer))
  {
    WinningPlayer = CurrentPlayer;
  }
  else
  {
    CurrentPlayer = CurrentPlayer == 'x' ? 'o' : 'x';
  }
}
```