# Tic-Tac-Toe Determine winner

Tags: c#, arrays, console, char

```
     public void CheckWin()
  {
     if (spillebræt[0, 0] == 'X' && spillebræt[1, 0] == 'X' && spillebræt[2, 0] == 'X')
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 wins!\nPress ENTER to end game");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Environment.Exit(0);
     }
  }
```

Spillebræt = game board. I am trying to create a method for determining the winner of a simple Console based game of Tic Tac Toe. For the game board i have a 2 dimensional char array, which is initially filled with '+' symbols. The player class shifts between the 2 players turns, checking whether a winner has been found each time. I guess i could use a lot of if statements for determining the winner as there are 8 possible solutions, but i am looking for a way that uses less line space. The above code shows my initial approach (checking every possible solution through if statements).

Comment: I would have though there were 16 possible solutions in this format as you also have the `'O'`'s to think about.

Comment: You will have to set all possible winning combinations by using if statments

Comment: @Shaharyar I don't think so. There are other options.

Comment: @AndrewMao I would say that indeed this is a duplicate.

Comment: @OscarMederos I meant that he will have to define all combinations, its not necessary that he should use if statements.

Comment: I would think there's an easy solution in a magic square http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square

Comment: Duplicate? I just wrote this question myself. But thx for answers. I'll have a look at the question linked.

Comment: @user2104751 **duplicate** means that this question (or a very similar one) was asked before, not necessarily by you.

Comment: THe magic square solution looks interesting. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a matrix with all winning cases and check if the current state is a winning state:

```
        // Example
        var matrix = new[,] { { "O", "+", "+" }, { "O", "+", "+" }, { "O", "+", "+" } };

        var wins = new List<string> {
             "100100100", // 1st column vertical
             "010010010", // 2nd column vertical
             "001001001", // 3rd column vertical
             "111000000", // 1st row horizontal
             "000111000", // 2nd row horizontal
             "000000111", // 3rd row horizontal
             "100010001", // top-left bottom-right diagonal
             "001010100"  // top-right bottom-left diagonal
            };

        // Crosses (X)
        var check = new List<string> {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"};
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                if (matrix[i, j] == "X") check[i*3 + j] = "1";
        if (wins.Contains(string.Join("", check))) { /* crosses win */ }

        // Circles (O)
        check = new List<string> { "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0" };
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                if (matrix[i, j] == "O") check[i * 3 + j] = "1";
        if (wins.Contains(string.Join("", check))) { /* circles win */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always write all the various cases but it's cumbersome, and doesn't scale (what if you want to extend the board?).

So I would suggest a more involved implementation as an exercise.

You create a `Line` class, with a start and an end point. You also implement a *Move to next line* operator on the `Line`, which rotates it. You can then simply cycle through all the lines by moving start points and end points following an easy rule.

Then, you make an operator on your board that lets you *apply* a line to the board, and returns true if every board case on the path of the line is of the same sign.

This way, you can simply check if a board position is a winning one by using something like:

```
for (Line l = new Line() ; l.Valid() ; l.MoveToNextLine())
{
    if (board.WinningLine(l))
        return true;
}
return false;
```

Of course, you can then customize as you feel like such as replace `MoveToNextLine` by an `operator ++`, etc. And you should have an `end` state on your line, so that you can jump out of the loop and not continue over and over.

The `MoveToNextLine` would be just moving around your start and end points according an order you decide.

And now you can see that if you want to extend your game on a `n x n` board, it's gonna be very easy: you'll just have to update `MoveToNextLine`.